# JsTestDriver - Missing artifact error

Tags: unit-testing, maven-plugin, maven-3, js-test-driver

I'm trying to integrate **JsTestDriver** to **Maven** to test also my scripts before deploying.
Actually I follow up the steps described at Google Code [here](http://code.google.com/p/jstd-maven-plugin/wiki/GettingStarted). But unfortunately I'm not able to resolve dependency. Despite I added repository and plugin-repository to my Maven **settings.xml**, I still get error '**Missing artifact com.googlecode.jstd-maven-plugin:jstd-maven-plugin:jar:1.3.2.5**'.

I'll be so happy if someone can corrent/guide me.

Thanks in advance.

With regards.

**settings.xml**

```
// ..................
<repository>
    <id>jstd-maven-plugin google code repo</id>
    <url>http://jstd-maven-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/maven2</url>
</repository>
<pluginRepository>
    <id>jstd-maven-plugin google code repo</id>
    <url>http://jstd-maven-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/maven2</url>
</pluginRepository>
// ..................
```

**pom.xml**

```
// ..................
<properties>
    <jstd.version>1.3.2.5</jstd.version>
</properties>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.jstd-maven-plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstd-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${jstd.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<plugin>
<groupId>com.googlecode.jstd-maven-plugin</groupId>
<artifactId>jstd-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>${jstd.version}</version>
<configuration>
    <port>9876</port>
    <reset>true</reset>
    <verbose>true</verbose>
    <server>localhost:9876</server>
    <runnerMode>INFO</runnerMode>
    <config>src/test/resources/jsTestDriver.conf</config>
    <jar>src/test/resources/JsTestDriver-1.3.4.b.jar</jar>
</configuration>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>run-tests</id>
        <phase>test</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>test</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
// ..................
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the below to your project pom.xml file:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>jstd-maven-plugin google code repo</id>
        <url>http://jstd-maven-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/maven2</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>jstd-maven-plugin google code repo</id>
        <url>http://jstd-maven-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/maven2</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Hope this helps.